# Automapper configuration problem, structural difference

Tags: c#, automapper

I am struggling to configure automaper for following scenario, where there is an extra level of indirection at the source level.

On DB layer we have structure:

`ResultDB` (hasa) `List<CaseTriageResultDB>` and `CaseTriageResultDB` has a `TriageResultDB`

On DTO layer we have structure:

`ResultDTO` (hasa) `List<TriageResultDTO>`

I want to configure automapper to map `ResultDB` objects to `ResultDTO` objects. Here is a (failing) test with dummy classes to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class TriageResultDB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class CaseTriageResultDB
{
    public TriageResultDB TriageResult { get; set; }
}
public class ResultDB
{
    public double EstimatedCost { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CaseTriageResultDB> CaseTriageResults { get; set; }
}

//-- DTOs (ResultDTO -> List<TriageResult>)
public class TriageResultDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class ResultDTO
{
    public double EstimatedCost { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TriageResultDTO> TriageResults { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    MapperConfiguration CreateConfig()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<TriageResultDB, TriageResultDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ResultDB, ResultDTO>();
        });

        return config;
    }

    [Test]
    public void MapFromDBtoDTO()
    {
        var config = CreateConfig();

        var resultDB = new ResultDB()
        {
            EstimatedCost = 100,
            CaseTriageResults = new List<CaseTriageResultDB>()
           {
                new CaseTriageResultDB() { TriageResult = new TriageResultDB() { Name = "triageResult1", Description = "description1" }},
                new CaseTriageResultDB() { TriageResult = new TriageResultDB() { Name = "triageResult2", Description = "description2" }}
            }
        };

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dto = mapper.Map<ResultDTO>(resultDB);

        Assert.AreEqual(100, dto.EstimatedCost);
        Assert.AreEqual("triageResult1", dto.TriageResults.First().Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("triageResult2", dto.TriageResults.Last().Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out myself, something like:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ResultDB, ResultDTO>()
.ForMember(dto => dto.TriageResults,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(db => db.CaseTriageResults.Select(dbTriageResult => dbTriagResult.TriageResult)));
```